# audio tag won't read files from the computer

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio, src

So, when I make something like that:

```
<audio src="sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg" controls>
```

It won't work (The player dissapears in FF), but when I replace the directory with a link from Dropbox, it works!
The website is hosted from my Dropbox account with a custom domain. The path should work because other things, like images or fonts, are working.

Comment: Are you trying to play files from the local computer or server? This might be helpful http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me. **Are you sure that path to file is ok?**
I test this code on FF 28.

```
<audio src="sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg" controls>
```

If the path to file is not correct then no audio control is displayed.